# searching all subdirectories for certain files, skipping some folders

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get all paths to all files with a certain extension but skipping certain folders. I use this code which works fine but does not exclude the specified folders.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    try
    {
        var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                .Where(y => !y.Contains("Program Files") || !y.Contains("Windows"))
                .SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
        }
        return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

But based on my research of other questions this is exactly what I should be doing. Where am I going wrong please?

Usage would be:

```
var enumerable = EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Before we can tell what you are doing wrong we need to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you want to exlude `Program Files` **and** `Windows`, so use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
.Where(y => !y.Contains("Program Files") && !y.Contains("Windows"))
```