# Directory.EnumerateFiles method: How to enumerate files in specified subdirectories?

Tags: c#, linq

Assume the following directory structure. "C:\Genre" and the "Genre" directory having several subdirectories: "Rock", "Pop", "Metal", "Jazz".

How would I tweak the following statement to search in "Rock" and "Metal" subdirectories only?

```
var myFiles = Directory.
    EnumerateFiles("C:\Genre", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
    Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
```

Comment: You search in C:\Genre\Rock and C:\Genre\Metal and combine the results? Though i'm not sure if gifs && jpgs will do for music ;)

Comment: @Icepickle Maybe OP is looking for album art and/or covers! :-)

Comment: Since the search pattern doesn't allow regular expressions or any other fancy stuff, you're down to making 2 searches or have a where condition like `(s => (s.ToLower().Contains("rock") || s.ToLower().Contains("metal")) && (s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"))`.

Comment: Good stuff! In my defense, I did choose Rock and Metal! :) I am always shooting for something generic in nature. I will likely be grabbing a search string I can parse from a configuration file and working it into my statement. Tweaking the where condition may be an option. Decisions... Thanks!

Comment: Related question: [searching all subdirectories for certain files, skipping some folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644885/).

Comment: Related question: [How to filter Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple criteria?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider some implementation like this one:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var directoryPaths = new List<string>
            {
                @"C:\root\path_1",
                @"C:\root\path_2",
                @"C:\root\path_3"
                // …
            };
        var searchPatterns = new List<string>
            {
                "*.jpg",
                "*.gif"
            };

        var filePaths = directoryPaths
            .SelectMany(directoryPath =>
                EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, searchPatterns, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();

        // …
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(
        string path,
        IEnumerable<string> searchPatterns,
        SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        var filePaths = searchPatterns.SelectMany(
            searchPattern => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption));
        return filePaths;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I am huge fan of this solution... I tweaked my project respectively. However, I am seeing a filePaths count of 0.

Comment: @80sRocker, sorry, that was my mistake. Please see the update.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input! I like this solution. However, I am curious if I would run into any performance issues if I were working with 100k files etc? Thanks!

Comment: @80sRocker, you are welcome! Sorry, it is hard to tell: it would be better to measure performance in a concrete context.

Comment: Sergey, How can I add a blob file that does not have a file extension to the searchPatterns List? Thanks!

Comment: @80sRocker, please consider using `"*."` as a search pattern value.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the clean way would be search each directory you want, and then add them up in the `myFiles`

```
var rockFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\Genre\Rock", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
var metalFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\Genre\Metal", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
var myFiles = RockFiles.Concat(MetalFiles);
```

Now, if you want a generic way to do so, that would be a different story, and a bit more complex one :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Concat in Linq to combine the files in two directories.

```
var rockFiles = Directory.
EnumerateFiles("C:\Genre\Rock", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var metalFiles = Directory.
EnumerateFiles("C:\Genre\Metal", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var myFiles = rockFile
.Concat(metalFiles)
.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));
```

Comment: Since you're guaranteed there won't be any duplicates between the two Enumerables, you should probably use Concat instead of Union and avoid possible duplicate searches.

Comment: Yep you are right. I just couldn't think of the name 'Concat'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two arrays for the extensions  and the `Path`-class:

```
var myFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Temp\Genre", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fn => genres.Contains(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fn)), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
          && extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fn), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

`Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fn))` returns the folder-name of a file-path.